# Script in html does not work

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, input

I tried to add some javascript in `details.html` in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address` like in code below.

**details.html :**

```
<div class="billing-address-details" data-bind="if: isAddressDetailsVisible() && currentBillingAddress()">
    <p id="test"></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="test3" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="test2" data-bind="value: currentBillingAddress().prefix"/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().prefix --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: currentBillingAddress().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value != null -->
                <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value == null -->
                <!-- ko text: element[attribute] --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button style="visibility:hidden;" type="button"
            class="action action-edit-address"
            data-bind="visible: !isAddressSameAsShipping(), click: editAddress">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cek($prefix)
    {
        alert($prefix);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = $prefix ;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // cek(document.getElementById("test2").value);
        document.getElementById('test3').value='text to be displayed' ; 
    });
</script>
```

I want to change the input with id `test3` with the value of input with id `test2`, but it's not work with my code below, is there something wrong with my script?

Comment: yeah don't add it in the `vendor` file - override it using a custom module and phtml template

Comment: its not clear you can add  data-bind="value: currentBillingAddress().prefix"  in test 3 No?

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet im just testing it so i can do another function, but it's not even work with a simple script.

Comment: Actualy you must override a js linekd to this template, find by "editAddress" function, and add your function with bata-bind= with an specified event like click ot other